# How to flatten an XML file into a set of xpath expressions?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Consider I have the following example XML file:

```
<ns1:create xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/'>
   <article xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>
      <name xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>foo</name>
      <description xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>bar</description>
      <price xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'>
         <amount xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'>00.00</amount>
         <currency xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'>USD</currency>
      </price>
      <id xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>1</id>
   </article>
</ns1:create>
```

What would be the best (most efficient) way to flatten this into a set of xpath expressions.
Note also: I want to ignore any namespace and attribute information. (If needed, this could also be done as a pre-processing step).

So I want get as output:

```
/create/article/name
/create/article/description
/create/article/price/amount
/create/article/price/currency
/create/article/id
```

I’m implementing in Java.

**EDIT:**
PS, I might also need this to work in the case that there is no data at the text node, so for example, this following should generate the same output as the above:

```
<ns1:create xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/'>
  <article xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>
    <name />
    <description />
    <price xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'>
      <amount />
      <currency xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'></currency>
    </price>
    <id xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'></id>
  </article>
</ns1:create>
```

Comment: I’m trying to hope for something more reliable than just a manual approach of iterating over the document, etc. For example: we also need to consider multi-elements, which could transform into /field[0] and /field[1], etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this pretty easily with XSLT. Looking at your examples, it seems like you only want the XPath of elements that contain text. If that's not the case, let me know and I can update the XSLT.

I created a new input example to show how it handles siblings with the same name. In this case, `<article>`.

**XML Input**

```
<ns1:create xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/'>
    <article xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>
        <name xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>foo</name>
        <description xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>bar</description>
        <price xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'>
            <amount xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'>00.00</amount>
            <currency xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'>USD</currency>
        </price>
        <id xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>1</id>
    </article>
    <article xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>
        <name xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>some name</name>
        <description xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>some description</description>
        <price xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/2/'>
            <amount xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/2/'>00.01</amount>
            <currency xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/2/'>USD</currency>
        </price>
        <id xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>2</id>
    </article>
</ns1:create>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[text()]">
        <xsl:call-template name="genPath"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="genPath">
        <xsl:param name="prevPath"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currPath" select="concat('/',local-name(),'[',
        count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])+1,']',$prevPath)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="parent::*">
            <xsl:call-template name="genPath">
                <xsl:with-param name="prevPath" select="$currPath"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="not(parent::*)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$currPath"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
/create[1]/article[1]/name[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/description[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/amount[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/currency[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/id[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/name[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/description[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/amount[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/currency[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/id[1]
```

---

**UPDATE**

For the XSLT to work for all elements, simply remove the `[text()]` predicate from `match="*[text()]"`. This will output the path for every element. If you don't want the path output for elements that contain other elements (like create, article, and price) add the predicate `[not(*)]`. Here's an updated example:

**New XML Input**

```
<ns1:create xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/'>
    <article xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>
        <name />
        <description />
        <price xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'>
            <amount />
            <currency xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'></currency>
        </price>
        <id xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'></id>
    </article>
    <article xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>
        <name xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>some name</name>
        <description xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>some description</description>
        <price xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/2/'>
            <amount xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/2/'>00.01</amount>
            <currency xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/2/'>USD</currency>
        </price>
        <id xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>2</id>
    </article>
</ns1:create>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:call-template name="genPath"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="genPath">
        <xsl:param name="prevPath"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currPath" select="concat('/',local-name(),'[',
            count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])+1,']',$prevPath)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="parent::*">
            <xsl:call-template name="genPath">
                <xsl:with-param name="prevPath" select="$currPath"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="not(parent::*)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$currPath"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
/create[1]/article[1]/name[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/description[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/amount[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/currency[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/id[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/name[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/description[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/amount[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/currency[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/id[1]
```

If you remove the `[not(*)]` predicate, this is what the output looks like (a path is output for every element):

```
/create[1]
/create[1]/article[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/name[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/description[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/amount[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/currency[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/id[1]
/create[1]/article[2]
/create[1]/article[2]/name[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/description[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/amount[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/currency[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/id[1]
```

Here's another version of the XSLT that is about 65% faster:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',local-name(),'[',count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())])+1,']')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution, however, could you please consider the case when there is no data at the text node? I have edited my question my outlining a sample of such. thnx.

Comment: @Larry - Please see my update. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I also made a small change so that any attribute values wouldn't get dumped to the output.

Comment: Thanks very much... :) This is perfect! On another note: would there be a solution for the reverse of this problem? I.e. starting with an XML template and given a set of XPaths and values, be able to generate the populated XML file. Anyway, I’ve asked this as another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385323); if you know a solution to this as well, would be great!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use a SAX parser. [wiki entry for SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) , [Xerces: a SAX parser for java by Apache](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/)

On each start element, add the name of the element onto the end of a list. On each end element, remove the last list entry. When you run into content, and you want to output your xpath, it can be retrieved by iterating the list.