# Parse XML file to get all Namespace information

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I want to be able to get all namespace information from a given XML File.

So for example, if the input XML File is something like:

```
<ns1:create xmlns:ns1="http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/">
   <ns1:article xmlns:ns1="xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/">
      <ns1:id>1</ns1:id>
      <description>bar</description>
      <name>foo</name>
      <ns1:price>
         <amount>00.00</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </ns1:price>
      <ns1:price>
         <amount>11.11</amount>
         <currency>AUD</currency>
      </ns1:price>
   </ns1:article>
   <ns1:article xmlns:ns1="xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/">
      <ns1:id>2</ns1:id>
      <description>some name</description>
      <name>some description</name>
      <ns1:price>
         <amount>00.01</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </ns1:price>
   </ns1:article>
</ns1:create>
```

I would like to expect an output that looks something like this (in this case comma-separated):

```
create, ns1, http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/
article, ns1, http://predic8.com/material/1/
price, ns1, http://predic8.com/material/1/
id, ns1, http://predic8.com/material/1/
```

Important notes:

It is important that we also consider sub-nodes which are defined within a specific namespace, but whose definition may be defined at a higher node. For example, we would still like to pick up the node `ns1:id`, where we need to trace back to the parent node `ns1:article` to discover that the namespace url is `xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/`

I am implementing in Java, so I would not mind either a Java-based solution, or even a XSLT-based solution might seem appropriate.

Comment: So what kind of information are you looking for exactly? The first line in your output has a local name, a namespace prefix and a namespace name, the next three lines however end with something looking like a namespace declaration attribute strangely lacking the closing `'` delimiter however. And what about qualified names of attribute nodes, are you interested in them as well?

Comment: Thanks, I’ve edited the question now, as that was an error. I am really after getting a triple in the form of (local-name, prefix, url). Also, for now I don’t want to worry about qualified attribute nodes.

Comment: Larry, it may be good to point out the fact that the currently-accepted answer neither deals with names in a default namespace nor with namespaced attribute names. Also it is over-complicated and rather unreadable. Compare this to an XSLT 2.0 solution which in fact is the evaluation of a single XPath expression -- as provided in the other two answers...

Comment: Dimitre, I certainly agree, and while I know it was not explicitly stipulated in the question, it would seem to be key requirements for a complete solution. As after all, I did mention “all” namespace information. Thanks for pointing this out and providing a solution to address this, (+1). I have also accordingly modified the correct answer to reflect the more correct solution.

Comment: Larry, whilst your questions may be interesting and challenging, we do expect you to have attempted to solve these problems by yourself (and post your code as well, even if it doesn't work) rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Further developed the XPath expression proposed by Michael Kay** (seems actually as a simplification) to also process unprefixed element names that belong to a default namespace:

```
distinct-values(//*[namespace-uri()]
                    /concat(local-name(),
                            ', ',
                            substring-before(name(), ':'),
                            ', ',
                            namespace-uri(),
                            '&#xA;'
                            )
                )
```

**When this XPath expression is evaluated on the following document** (the provided one but with an added element that is in a default namespace):

```
<ns1:create xmlns:ns1="http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/">
    <ns1:article xmlns:ns1="xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/">
        <ns1:id>1</ns1:id>
        <description>bar</description>
        <name>foo</name>
        <ns1:price>
            <amount>00.00</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </ns1:price>
        <ns1:price>
            <amount>11.11</amount>
            <currency>AUD</currency>
        </ns1:price>
    </ns1:article>
    <ns1:article xmlns:ns1="xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/">
        <ns1:id>2</ns1:id>
        <description>some name</description>
        <name>some description</name>
        <ns1:price>
            <amount>00.01</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </ns1:price>
        <quality xmlns="my:q">high</quality>
    </ns1:article>
</ns1:create>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
 create, ns1, http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/
 article, ns1, xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/
 id, ns1, xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/
 price, ns1, xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/
 quality, , my:q
```

A further, slight improvement is also to produce the namespace data for attribute names:

```
distinct-values(//(*|@*)[namespace-uri()]
                    /concat(if(. intersect ../@*)
                              then '@'
                              else (),
                            local-name(),
                            ', ',
                            substring-before(name(), ':'),
                            ', ',
                            namespace-uri(),
                            '&#xA;'
                            )
                )
```

**When this XPath expression is evaluated on the following XML document** (the previous one (above) with added an `xml:lang` attribute on one of the `article` elements):

```
<ns1:create xmlns:ns1="http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/">
    <ns1:article xml:lang="en-us" xmlns:ns1="xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/">
        <ns1:id>1</ns1:id>
        <description>bar</description>
        <name>foo</name>
        <ns1:price>
            <amount>00.00</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </ns1:price>
        <ns1:price>
            <amount>11.11</amount>
            <currency>AUD</currency>
        </ns1:price>
    </ns1:article>
    <ns1:article xmlns:ns1="xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/">
        <ns1:id>2</ns1:id>
        <description>some name</description>
        <name>some description</name>
        <ns1:price>
            <amount>00.01</amount>
            <currency>USD</currency>
        </ns1:price>
        <quality xmlns="my:q">high</quality>
    </ns1:article>
</ns1:create>
```

**again the correct result is produced:**

```
 create, ns1, http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/
 article, ns1, xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/
 @lang, xml, http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace
 id, ns1, xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/
 price, ns1, xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/
 quality, , my:q
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with a single XPath 2.0 expression:

```
distinct-values(//*[name()!=local-name()]/
   concat(local-name(), ', ', substring-before(name(), ':'), ', ', namespace-uri())
```

Comment: It seems that this doesn't cover element names in a default namespace -- or am I wrong?

Comment: It can easily be adapted to handle element names in the default namespace or in no namespace by changing the predicate, but the question didn't make it clear what the requirement was, so I guessed.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the built-in [XMLStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html), which is the interface implemented by the streaming XML parser (get to it from the `XMLInputFactory` class). Its `getName` method returns a QName, which should give you everything you need.

Something along the lines of:

```
File file = new File("samples/sample11.xml");
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));
Set<String> namespaces = new HashSet<String>();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
      int evt = reader.next();
      if (evt == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
        QName qName = reader.getName();
        if(qName != null){
            if(qName.getPrefix() != null && qName.getPrefix().compareTo("")!=0)
                namespaces.add(String.format("%s, %s, %s",
                    qName.getLocalPart(), qName.getPrefix(), qName.getNamespaceURI()));
        }
      }
}

for(String namespace : namespaces){
    System.out.println(namespace);              
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, this works well. I’ve edited your solution to provide a more complete solution (at the moment, it’s still awaiting peer-review).