# Find all prefix:url namespaces in an XML file - quickly

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

We need to find all prefix:namespace pairs in an XML file. We allow users to supply any XML file and any XPath to query on it. We need to find the prefix:uri mappings to set those when the XPath is evaluated.

We presently use:

```
selectNodes("//namespace::*[name() != 'xml'][not(../../namespace::*=.)]");
```

and this does return all pairs. The problem is that it is slow. I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437606/parse-xml-file-to-get-all-namespace-information) but it also is slow. Is there a fast way to do this? And I need this solely to perform XPath queries against the XML.

I'm doing this both in Java (using dom4j) and .NET.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do lots of changes to the code provided in the answers to the linked question provided by [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11441838/695343) and [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444940/695343).

This code (also theirs) touches each node (elements and attributes) exactly once, so runtime for everything inside `distinct-values()` is `O(n)` on the number of nodes. In worst case, each node has some namespace attached, so you will have to sort these n nodes which is `O(n*log n)` for any reasonable sort algorithm.

```
(: each namespace:uri-combination only once :)
distinct-values(
  (: analyze all nodes with namespace set, both attributes and elements :)
  /descendant-or-self::*/(.|@*)[namespace-uri(.)]
  (: build result string :)
  /concat(
    substring-before(name(), ':'), ': ', namespace-uri(.), '&#xA;'
  )
)
```

Comment: distinct-values appears to be an XPath 2.0 addition. I need a solution that works in 1.0 (we're using dom4j in Java and the ADO.NET runtime in .NET).

Comment: Just remove it and `sort|uniq` the results in Java/.NET then.