# Select and append current node's text value in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery, xslt-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate/get xpath from XML node java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java)

This is a follow-on question from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297807) I’ve asked, (I’ve decided to ask as a separate question, as the previous seems to be getting too big).

I’ve got the following XSLT, which allows me to transform a specified XML String into a set of XPath expressions:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',local-name(),'[',count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())])+1,']')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For example, the XML String:

```
<ns1:create xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/wsdl/material/ArticleService/1/'>
    <article xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/'>
        <name />
        <description />
        <price xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/'>
            <amount />
            <currency xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/1/‘>AUD</currency>
        </price>
        <id xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/1/‘>1</id>
    </article>
    <article xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>
        <name xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>some name</name>
        <description xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>some description</description>
        <price xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/2/'>
            <amount xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/2/'>00.01</amount>
            <currency xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/common/2/'>USD</currency>
        </price>
        <id xmlns:ns1='http://predic8.com/material/2/'>2</id>
    </article>
</ns1:create>
```

Would get transformed into:

```
/create[1]/article[1]/name[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/description[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/amount[1]
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/currency[1] , AUD
/create[1]/article[1]/id[1] , 1
/create[1]/article[2]/name[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/description[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/amount[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/currency[1]
/create[1]/article[2]/id[1]
```

**My question:**
How, can I modify the XSLT so that I can also *select and append the current node’s text value*. Noting also that, as I've illustrated in the sample XML file supplied, some nodes may not contain text values, etc.

So for the sample above, I would expect something like (e.g. comma-separated output):

```
/create[1]/article[1]/name[1] , 
/create[1]/article[1]/description[1] , 
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/amount[1] , 
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/currency[1] , 
/create[1]/article[1]/id[1] , 
/create[1]/article[2]/name[1] , some name
/create[1]/article[2]/description[1] , some description
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/amount[1] , 00.01
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/currency[1] , USD
/create[1]/article[2]/id[1] , 2
```

Comment: **The answer is provided here**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java Just use it. I know applications for testing XSLT that use this as the core for tests of any XSLT transformation.

Comment: Thanks, that post is quite brilliant... wish I would have known about it earlier!

Comment: Yes, sure, it certainly looks a robust solution, and solves more of my complete problem (+1).

Comment: @Kev♦ Thank you for deleting my answer ... Besides closing the question, you could at least specify which is the duplicate question -- otherwise any interested reader wouldn't know where to look. I hope this is just a casual omission from your side and not a display of pedantic formalism with lack of thought -- which I hope no moderator should ever exhibit. If, unfortunately, this comment is embarassing to you, I'll understand if you delete it. So will the people who have read this comment :)

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev There's a link at the top of the page that goes to the original question.  Kev didn't omit anything.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - your accepted answer linked to another question with an accepted answer. That means it's a duplicate, it's standard procedure that we close these questions as dupes and delete such answers as yours. Next time just flag as a duplicate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should as simple as adding a `select=./text()` at the appropriate node, or have I missed something subtle in your question?

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',local-name(),'[',count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())])+1,']')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text> , </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
/create[1]/article[1]/name[1] , 
/create[1]/article[1]/description[1] , 
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/amount[1] , 
/create[1]/article[1]/price[1]/currency[1] , AUD
/create[1]/article[1]/id[1] , 1
/create[1]/article[2]/name[1] , some name
/create[1]/article[2]/description[1] , some description
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/amount[1] , 00.01
/create[1]/article[2]/price[1]/currency[1] , USD
/create[1]/article[2]/id[1] , 2
```